Run Python script in Pentaho CE 9.4 PDI
I'm running Pentaho PDI CE 9.4 version. I want to execute a Python script. How to do that in the current version? 
I also checked the Python Executor plugin but that's not available for 9.4.
What to do now?
Thanks :)
Run python script in Pentaho CE 9.4 version

I would address this question to the Pentaho product service site.
